# Error install phpMyAdmin

Tags: 16.04, mysql, phpmyadmin

I install phpMyAdmin but I have this error

[image]

I modify file `phpmyadmin.conf` in `etc/dbconfig-common` when I set `dbc_dbport` to `0` and I try with `80`, then launch this command:

```
dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

but again the error.

Comment: What error did you get from the dpkg-reconfigure?

Comment: Had you recently upgraded your OS?